# How to use mysqli connection with SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysqli

I'm trying to make a secure connection with my database

I wrote the following code:

```
<?php

// form filled?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = 'gebruiker';
    $pass = 'gebruiker';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, 'forum');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'database doesnt work';
        file_put_contents('MySQLiErrors.txt', date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]') .          mysqli_connect_error() . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        exit();
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userspassword = $_POST['password'];
        $salt = strrev($userspassword . substr(0, 4));
        $password = hash('sha512', $userspassword . $salt);
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $statement->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->get_result();
        $statement->close();
        $count = $result->num_rows;
        if ($count > 0) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
            header("Location: forum.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['Error'] = "Invalid username or password";
        }
    }
    $db->close();
}
```

I also read something about SSL connections on php.net but I don't have any idea how to implement this in this case.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

My code is running on fedora 21 and it works fine but the next thing I want is a secure connection using SSL.

Comment: since your are using your MySQL connection on the same server there is no need to use an SSL connection between php and your MySQL server ... are you looking to secure the connection between your end user and your web server?

Comment: you're connecting to `localhost`. that'll use a local unix-domain socket. There is no point in using ssl. SSL might be useful if you were doing a remote connection via TCP, but ssl-over-unixdomain? Rather pointless.

Comment: SHA is too fast for passwords.  Use bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Deriving the salt from the password completely defeats the purpose of salt.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SLaks but the issue here is that I want to know how to make an ssl connection

Comment: @cmorrissey that's correct

Answer (score 27):

You do NOT need the client certificate and private key and in most cases you do NOT want MySQL server to verify the client certificate.

Client however MUST verify server certificate using CA certificate to prevent MITM.

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt", NULL, NULL);
$mysqli->real_connect('hostname', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is one of the most helpful answers I've seen - the documentation is poor (as far as I can tell - perhaps my issue with not finding what's out there). The issue of certificate validation (server) and ignoring client is spot on. And seems to answer the OP exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Is `$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);` necessary? That option does not seem to be [documented](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php). Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299690/does-mysqli-verify-server-certificates-by-default-when-using-ssl

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_init();
if (!$con)
  {
  die("mysqli_init failed");
  }

mysqli_ssl_set($con,"key.pem","cert.pem","cacert.pem",NULL,NULL); 

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,"localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"))
  {
  die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

// Some queries...

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

connection -    Required. Specifies the MySQL connection to use

---

key -   Required. Specifies the path name to the key file

---

cert -  Required. Specifies the path name to the certificate file

---

ca -    Required. Specifies the path name to the certificate authority file

---

capath -    Required. Specifies the pathname to a directory that contains trusted SSL CA certificates in PEM format

---

cipher  - Required. Specifies a list of allowable ciphers to use for SSL encryption

[SOURCE HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_ssl_set.asp)

For mysql_real_connect use

```
<?php
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set('/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem', '/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem', '/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, 'ip', 'user', 'pass', 'db', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$link)
{
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r ($res);
    $db->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: I hope you know what is key.pem and cert.pem files

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with those. But what about sql injection if you use mysqli_real_connect?

Comment: where do you use the prepared statement on the $link or on the $db?

Comment: what do you mean "where do you use"

Comment: The prepared statements of the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73099/discussion-between-themaster-and-anri).

Comment: Your example(s) helped tremendously.  Thank you.

Comment: Is `mysqli_options($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);` necessary? That option does not seem to be [documented](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php). Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299690/does-mysqli-verify-server-certificates-by-default-when-using-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Little easy way convienance to actucaly mysqli

```
<?php  namespace mysqlConnect;


class mymysqli extends \mysqli {


        
        public function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $persistent = true, $ssl = false, $certpublic = "") {
            //$this->close();
            parent::init();
            //parent::options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
            if($ssl) {
                parent::options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, false);
                parent::ssl_set(NULL, NULL, $certpublic, NULL, NULL);
            }
            @parent::real_connect(($this->persistent ? 'p:' : '') . $this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);

        }
}
```